# effective vs real user ID : why doesn't it return root as effective ID in my example?

Tags: root, setuid

I did some reading about the difference between real and effective user ID. I thought I understood, but I have a doubt : according to my comprehension, in the example below the command `$ id -un` should return `root` as effective user, not `jack` :

```
$ sudo cp /usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/bashroot
$ sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/bashroot
$ ls -l /usr/bin/bashroot 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 1234376 oct.  25 15:42 /usr/bin/bashroot

$ bashroot

$ id -un
jack

$ id -unr
jack
```

`bashroot` has setuid and belongs to `root`, so according to my comprehension I expected `$ id -un` to return `root`, not `jack`.

What do I miss ?

[EDIT]
More specifically, why doesn't `/usr/bin/bashroot` behave like `/usr/bin/passwd`, given that both have setuid ?

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/passwd 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 63960 févr.  7  2020 /usr/bin/passwd

$ ls -l /usr/bin/bashroot 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 1234376 oct.  25 15:42 /usr/bin/bashroot

$ passwd
Changing password for jack.
Current password:
```

Then, in another terminal :

```
$ bashroot

$ ps -a | grep passwd
1682362 pts/3    00:00:00 passwd
$ ps -eo pid,ruid,euid | grep 1682362
1682362  1000     0

$ ps -a | grep bashroot
1682405 pts/4    00:00:00 bashroot
$ ps -eo pid,ruid,euid | grep 1682405
1682405  1000  1000
```

The effective UID of `passwd` is `root` (0), which is expected. Why is the effective UID of `bashroot` 1000 (`jack`) and not `root` ?

[EDIT2 : OS]

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
11.6
$ uname -a
Linux d11work 5.10.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.158-2 (2022-12-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

[EDIT3]
See [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/759826/effective-vs-real-user-id-why-doesnt-it-return-root-as-effective-id-in-my-exa#answer-759829) :

```
$ bashroot -p

# id -un
root

# id -unr
jack
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash enforces this: if it is setuid, but isn’t run [in privileged mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) (look for `-p`), it sets the effective user id to the real user id:

> If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the `-p` option is not supplied, these actions are taken and the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the `-p` option is supplied at startup, the effective user id is not reset. Turning this option off causes the effective user and group ids to be set to the real user and group ids.

To get the effect you’re looking for, you need to run `bashroot -p`. You’ll notice the difference immediately: the shell prompt is `#` instead of `$`.